# how react send data using post url to web service

Tags: react-native

I created react native sign up page and i want to send data to web service through post request. I want to authenticate data in web service ,can give suggestion how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example :

```
fetch('http://justanexample.altervista.org/saveinfo.php', {

method: 'POST',
  headers: { 
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
           },
  body: JSON.stringify({text: "blablabla", id_product: "12"})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By using redux-saga and axios in your project you can structure your code nicely without having the whole fetch method in your js files.

Answer (score 0):

you will need an authentication API to authenticate user if you have an api then just do this...

```js
SignInUser = async () => {
    
    this.setState({
     username: this.state.username,
     password:this.state.password,
   })

   if(this.state.username && this.state.password !== null){
    try{
      this.setState({
        loading:true
      })
      const response = await fetch('YOUR API', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: this.state.username,
          password: this.state.password
        })
      });
      var promiseResponse = await response.json()
      console.log(promiseResponse.token);
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('LoginToken', JSON.stringify(promiseResponse.token));
        console.log('Token Stored In Async Storage');
        let tokenFromAsync = await AsyncStorage.getItem('LoginToken');
        console.log('Getting Token From Async...')
        tokenFromAsync = JSON.parse(tokenFromAsync)
        if(tokenFromAsync !== null){
          console.log(tokenFromAsync);
          this.setState({
            loading:false
          })
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Tabnav');
        }
        
      } catch (error) {
        // saving error
        console.log(`ERROR OCCURED ${error}`)
      }
      //this.props.navigation.navigate('Tabnav')
     } catch(error){
       console.log(`COULDN'T SIGN IN ${error}`)
     }
   } else {
     this.setState({
       msg:'Invalid Credentials',
       label:'red'
     });
   }
   
  
   
 }
```